# safe way of including a function in R environment

Tags: r

I have wrote a bunch of functions for my project for users to invoke interactively.

Now I'd like to have them safely included in the session.

I want to avoid a scenario where user types `rm(list=ls())` and erases my functions from memory.

Initially I tried to save function to another environment and attach that environment to search path but along the way I changed something and `R` is not longer able to find my function.

My code is split among multiple files but snippet below ilustrates how are things organised, normally user will run `app.R` because it contains refernces to other files, configurations etc.:

./funs.R

```
id.mapping.env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
attach(id.mapping.env)

id.mapping.env$test_function<- function() {
  print("It works")
}
```

./app.R

```
source("./funs.R")
test_function
```

If I run app.R I get error:

> Error: could not find function "test_function"

Why won't R find my function? Do I have to resort to writing my own package to ensure all of my functions can be found? 
I am not familiar with writing packages, if this is needed could you give me a tiny demo/tutorial(which I am googling right now).

Comment: It sounds like you probably should be writing a package. It's actually not that hard to do (anymore, at least) - I found this tutorial helpful for getting started: https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "won't find your function"? Also, I don't think your attach is really doing anything; it doesn't "update" when you add new items to the environment -- it copies the current version of whatever you attach. (And generally attach should be avoided). How exactly are users sending you code to run?

Comment: Thanks @HFBrowning, looking into it.

Comment: @MrFlick I'll update the question to elaborate further

Comment: Just move the `attach()` to the bottom of the file.

Comment: I strongly agree with the advice to avoid "attach". Its dangerous because when you want to detach, you must have as many detach's as you had attaches or you'll leave an old copy there. This can make for a miserable time trying to figure out what the problem is.